# How to make render toggle visible by default in 2.8?

Tags: rendering, outliner

I'd like to make the render toggle icon appear in the outliner by default - so I don't have to turn it on every time start a new project. Possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a new file and set up things the way you like and then save your start up file.
It's located under the file menu.

File > Defaults > Save Start Up File